# _fopen$UNIX2003 referenced from OpenSSL problem

Tags: c, iphone, openssl, rsa

I'm using compiled OpenSSL for an iPhone app. I followed the instructions here http://www.x2on.de/kontakt/ so I could develop rsa operation on iPhone simulator. The problem is that I get this error when building the project:

> _fopen$UNIX2003 referenced from
>
> _BIO_new_file in libcrypto_i386.a(bss_file.o)
>   _file_ctrl in libcrypto_i386.a(bss_file.o) Symbol(s)
>   not found

Every time I invoke this function to get a public key:

> RSA * d2i_RSAPublicKey(RSA **a, const unsigned char **pp, long length);

Some places point this is a version problem so I should build openssl for a different architecture (currently using iPhoneOS3.2.sdk), is that right?

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://solutions.michaelbrooks.ca/2009/10/30/fopenunix2003/) and [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/building-for-earlier-os-versions-in.html) both suggest for Mac OS X that your problem is two different components compiled for two different SDKs.

You should try cleaning the project's build output (`make clean`) and rebuilding everything with the same compiler/SDK.

Comment: Yes, it might be, I ended up copying their libraries to my project and it works now. Nevertheless I remember editing my Makefile with a higher version (their's iPhone 3.1.2, mine's 3.2). I'll follow your advice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Just create new `*.c` file and copy this code to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

FILE *fopen$UNIX2003( const char *filename, const char *mode )
{
    return fopen(filename, mode);
}

int fputs$UNIX2003(const char *res1, FILE *res2){
    return fputs(res1,res2);
}

int nanosleep$UNIX2003(int val){
    return usleep(val);
}

char* strerror$UNIX2003(int errornum){
    return strerror(errornum);
}

double strtod$UNIX2003(const char *nptr, char **endptr){
    return strtod(nptr, endptr);
}

size_t fwrite$UNIX2003( const void *a, size_t b, size_t c, FILE *d )
{
    return fwrite(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Found this solution here: http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/35905/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-xcode-6-ios-8-beta-6/36538